# Isomorphism with tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $f$ : $\Bbb Z_2$
$\rightarrow$ $\Bbb Z_4$ given as  $f$($a$ + $2$$\Bbb Z$) = $2a$ + $\Bbb Z_4$ is a monomorphism . And knowing that <0,2> as subgroup of $\Bbb Z_4$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2$ how can I prove that the morphism $f$ $\otimes $ $1$ : $\Bbb Z_2$$\otimes $ $\Bbb Z_2$ 
$\rightarrow$ $\Bbb Z_4 \otimes $ $\Bbb Z_2$ is the zero morphism

Any help by sketching a proof  or proving this statement will be apreciated.

Comment: "that the morphism..." **what** ?

Comment: ...is the zero morphism

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, we have (as $\;\Bbb Z$- modules = abelian groups) for any basic tensor $\;a\otimes b\in \Bbb Z_2\otimes\Bbb Z_2\;$:

$$f\otimes1(a\otimes b):=f(a)\otimes b:=(2a)\times b=2(a\otimes b)=a\otimes (2b)=\ldots$$

Comment: Got it! Since b belongs to Z_2 and has order two then b2 =0 then the tensor product is also zero.Thanks Btw any help to prove f is monomorphism?? :/ @Timbuc

Comment: $$f(a)=f(b)\implies 2a=2b\pmod 4\implies 2(a-b)=0\pmod 4\implies$$$$ a-b=0\pmod 2\implies a=b\pmod 2$$